# Undefined index: desclength

Tags: prestashop

I got this notice in Prestashop 1.6.1.0 Stats>Catalog Evaluation.

```
Notice: Undefined index: desclength_zh in /var/www/1cdeli.com.cn/public_html/modules/statscheckup/statscheckup.php on line 259

Notice: Undefined index: desclength_en in /var/www/1cdeli.com.cn/public_html/modules/statscheckup/statscheckup.php on line 259
```

I had same issue before updating from 1.6.0.14.

Answer (score 0):

Control you have the same of latest version module, like this :

```
            foreach ($descriptions as $description)
            {
                if (isset($description['iso_code']) && isset($description['description']))
                    $row['desclength_'.$description['iso_code']] = Tools::strlen(strip_tags($description['description']));
                if (isset($description['iso_code']))
                {
                    $scores['description_'.$description['iso_code']] = ($row['desclength_'.$description['iso_code']] < Configuration::get('CHECKUP_DESCRIPTIONS_LT') ? 0 : ($row['desclength_'.$description['iso_code']] > Configuration::get('CHECKUP_DESCRIPTIONS_GT') ? 2 : 1));
                    $totals['description_'.$description['iso_code']] += $scores['description_'.$description['iso_code']];
                }
            }
```

Module Git: https://github.com/PrestaShop/statscheckup/blob/master/statscheckup.php